# MOUSE LAGs WHEN I EXTEND DISPLAY ON ANOTHER MONITOR

Tags: 16.04, command-line, mouse, hdmi, lts

I am running ubuntu 16.04 LTS when i extend my display to another screen(LG monitor) the mouse lags leaving a trail behind that doesn't change even when i downgrade the resolution. Any suggestions

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA`? Thanks.

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:22b1] (rev 35)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3809]
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post (like I asked), when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.